# Custom Emoji's and Animated Emoji's not working [discord.py-rewrite]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently built a simple command to test the format of custom emoji's and animated emoji's

Here is what the command was

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, text):
await ctx.send("<:ono:521148278079881219> You said %s" % text)
```

But the output message didn't send the custom emoji, instead it messaged

```
:ono: You said hello(the text i messaged in chat)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Client.get_emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.get_emoji) to get the `Emoji` object, then use that to build your string

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, text):
    ono = bot.get_emoji(521148278079881219)
    await ctx.send(f"{ono} You said {text}")
```

Comment: would it still function if the emoji is animated?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not sure.  (I don't use animated emojis for anything.)  Could you try it and let me know?

Comment: if i wanted to use the same thing in discord.py async, whats the function for it?

Comment: Using `discord.utils.get` on all the emojis the bot can see: `get(bot.get_all_emojis(), id='521148278079881219')`

Comment: thanks! the method u messaged for async didnt quite work directly as the bot wasnt in the server where the custom emoji was located, instead i created another server and shifted the custom emoji's there with my bot invited in it and now it works.